# centering a label in a FlexboxLayout of nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

In a flexbox layout i want to have an image on the left and a center label title on the right :

```
  <FlexboxLayout backgroundColor="#bada55" justifyContent="space-between" height="300" class="head">
    <Image :src="posts.image_url" stretch="aspectFit" class="head_img"/>
    <Label :text="posts.product_name" alignSelf="center" alignContent="center" class="title" textWrap="true"/>
  </FlexboxLayout>
```

in my case the label text is going to the right but is not center, any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. "a center label title on the right"? Can you edit your question with a screenshot of what you have and what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `textAlignment="center"` to the label.

```
 <FlexboxLayout backgroundColor="#bada55" justifyContent="space-between" height="300" class="head">
         <Image :src="posts.image_url" stretch="aspectFit" class="head_img"/>
         <Label :text="posts.product_name" alignSelf="center" alignContent="center" textAlignment="center" class="title" textWrap="true"/>
</FlexboxLayout>
```